# Calculating the length of a schema and storing it in the data base

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using node.js express.js and mongoose to develop my back end, I have this mongoose schema where I want to add a field called `NumberRecords` for every stored document this field will have the length value of the array csvData, I looked around some similar question here and I found I can use this `pre` function which I did but I get nothing on my database no field called `NumberRecords` is being added.

How do I fix this?

```
const rowSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  SESSION_ID: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  CARD_NUMBER: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },

  TERMINAL_ID: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  EXTERNAL_STAN: {
    type: String,
    required: false,
  },
  })
const csvSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    fileName: { type: String, required: true },
    csvData: { type: [rowSchema], required: true },
    NumberRecords: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

csvSchema.pre("validate", function (next) {
  this.NumberRecords = this.csvData.length;
  next();
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("csvRecords", csvSchema);
```

Comment: Hey @souhail, can you share the payload that you are trying to add in the database, as this should work fine.

Comment: Hey @dhruv479 thank you for your replay, what I am trying to add is the `NumberRecords` field which is the length of the array `rowSchema` so everything I add a new document I get the `NumberRecords` which indicates how many elements are in the array that was added

Comment: I tried doing the same with your code reference and it worked like charm for me. Advice you to check the payload and debug the pdevalidation hook in mongoose.

Comment: Hey @dhruv479 what version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: I am using mongoose@9.9.9

Comment: There is no such thing as mongoose@9.9.9...